# Plot an energy level diagram

Tags: plotting

I have the following list:

```
gs = {-0.4993484712, -0.4978548043, 
      -0.4940563241, -0.4836338315, 
      -0.4559910524, -0.3817524976, 
      -0.1667542598, -0.1206998794, 
      -0.1192191910, -0.1152026146, 
      -0.1046546835, -0.0769508374, 
      -0.0026840318};
```

I want to draw a plot using my list as The one in the picture below. How can I do so?

[image: image of an energy level diagram]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Plot[gs, {x, .2, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Axes -> {False, True}, 
 AspectRatio -> 2, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can process `gs` to get the coordinates for 13 lines and use those coordinates with `Graphics`:

```
linecoords = {{0.05, #}, {.25, #}} & /@ gs;

Graphics[{Line /@ linecoords}, 
 Axes -> {False, True}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, .25}, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: great! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Wisdom, you are welcome.

Comment: Dear @kglr can you tell me what part of your code produces the horizontal lines?

Comment: @Wisdom, as you can see from  the simpler example `Plot[{2, 5, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}]`  we are using `gs` as 13 different  _constant_  _functions_.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks again